# Filtering column based on matching conditions in another column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to perform a simple filtering using dplyr but it doesnt seem to work with what I want to do.

I want to filter a dataframe based on Time as an example when only if Time matches the `category`, then look at column `Value`.

[image]

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "SubjectID Treatment Time Value
                A1 Amutant T0 5.3
                B0 Control T0 4.8
                A3 Amutant T3 4
                B1 Control T1 3
                B3 Control T3 6.5
                C2 Bmutant T2 2
                C1 Bmutant T1 3")

df %>% 
  group_by (Time) %>% 
  filter (Time == "T0") %>%
  filter (Value <5)
```

This seems not what I exactly want to get because I want to subset the whole row of those that match `T0` values `<5`.

The results should be filtering out only those subjects with T0 higher than 5 but should not affect T1, T2, T3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for sth like this: `df %>% 
  filter (Time == "T0", Value <5)`

Comment: But I need to only look at Value <5 for Time==“T0” or else it will filter also those from T2,T3 and T4.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly You can use the subset function

```
subset(df, Time == "T0" & Value < 5 | Time != "T0")
```

dplyr

```
df %>% filter(Time == "T0" & Value < 5 | Time != "T0")
```

Comment: Similar to my reply above, I need to only filter based on T0 that should not affect other time values.

Comment: The last statement could be simplified to `df %>% filter(Time != "T0" | Value < 5)`

Comment: Can you explain abit more in detail what goes wrong? Since the code now removes the values from T0 with values > 5, and the other values remain.

Comment: I think it did work looking at the dataset, thanks a lot!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

It may be easiest to create a helper field that can be filtered on

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(isFilter = case_when(Time == "T0" & Value > 5 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  filter(isFilter == 0)

SubjectID Treatment Time Value isFilter
1        B0   Control   T0   4.8        0
2        A3   Amutant   T3   4.0        0
3        B1   Control   T1   3.0        0
4        B3   Control   T3   6.5        0
5        C2   Bmutant   T2   2.0        0
6        C1   Bmutant   T1   3.0        0
```

Comment: If you're only testing one condition, you might as well use the base `ifelse`; Better yet: `isFilter = as.numeric(Time == "T0" & Value > 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
dates <- rep(
  seq(as.numeric(as.Date("01-01-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
      as.numeric(as.Date("01-10-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y"))), 
  each = 24
)

value <- runif(length(dates), 1, 10)
time <- runif(length(dates), 0, 1) 

data <- cbind(dates, value, time)
data <- tibble::as_tibble(data)

out <- data %>% filter(value != 0 & time > 5)
isTRUE(sum(out$time < 5 | out$value == 0) == 0)
#[1] TRUE
```

!